# Is there a type with fixed size of two bytes for floating points in c?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, fixed-size-types

I need something like uint16_t but for floating point numbers instead of integer. I need to be able to convert a float to it so I can transfer it and convert back to float later (obviously I will lose some precision).
Is there a simple solution for this or should I do it manually?

Comment: No, there isn't. Anyway 16 bit floating point number don't really make sense. Sounds like an [XY Poblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: In other words: what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: well, it *can* make sense - my Casio PB-700 did have a half-precision data type, and it made a lot of sense in that context. :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia OK; it _could_ make sens 30 years ago when your computer had 1K of RAM, but nowadays is really doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelWalz https://twitter.com/FioraAeterna/status/575188977738608641

Comment: Why exactly do you need half precision? Memory constraints? Network constraints? Hardware register file constraints?

Comment: You can simply truncate your 32-bits float to 16-bits by forgetting 2 bytes of the mantissa if you want, or define your own 16-bit float format.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I'm a bit offended by your comment - 1 KB of RAM? What underpowered computers do you think my grandfather bought? The base configuration of the PB-700 was with a generous 4 KB of RAM, and mine was fully upgraded to a whopping 16 KB thanks to three costly 4 KB cartridges. 

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Disagree with [16 bit floating point number don't really make sense.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731745/is-there-a-type-with-fixed-size-of-two-bytes-for-floating-points-in-c#comment74506509_43731745) IEEE 754-2008  has defined a 16-bit FP type [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).  All problems, unless the answer is [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29), are XY problems. ;-)

Comment: @Matteo: My first computer was a Sinclair ZX80 with a whopping 1k of RAM alright. It cost 400 guilders and came without a power supply. And yet a friend and I managed to control our (analogue) synths with it. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Well, I'm modifying some code. The original code stores integer data as uint16_t and then transfers via BLE. My processing results in floating point data. So I'm trying to replace the original raw data with the processed data.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Well I'm not sure if I really need half precision. I'm just looking for possible solutions for my problem one of which is replacing the original uint16_t data with my floating point data.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Yes that's what I meant by doing it manually. I was just wondering if there is a simpler solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing in the C standard. [Some compilers do have __fp16](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html).

You can use [Q numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)), but these are limited in a fixed range.

If you really need *floating* point, with the exponent, then you should implement the [ieee standard half precision.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)

Regular artimetics work on the Q numbers. You should write your own arithmetic for the half precision. Unless [your compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html) support it.

Or go [open source](http://half.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, this is fine. The first sentence is an answer on its own; the rest is a number of suggested alternatives.